# What would cause mongodb to write a no-op with a full document

Tags: mongodb

While trying to diagnose high wait times, related to mongo's flowcontrol I found the below in the oplog.

I understand the purpose of the `n` op is "no-op" written periodically to avoid staleness, but a few things confuse me:

1. this DB is NEVER idle - why would it write a no-op if it wasn't idle?
2. why would the no-op contain the full body of an insert?
3. could the no-op have been written due to high write pressure causing a 10 second delay in replication?

```
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1651706364, 92),
    "t" : NumberLong(39),
    "h" : NumberLong(0),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "i",
    "ns" : "somedatabase.somecollection",
    "ui" : UUID("3e459c38-cd32-48b7-a971-7fbe35e19a16"),
    "wall" : ISODate("2022-05-04T23:19:24.715Z"),
    "lsid" : {
        "id" : UUID("bc49d8dc-35e2-4c3e-8aaa-c3b91f6e768c"),
        "uid" : BinData(0,"fBoXTP6tMwXzKDWLLyql/yjO5/7aXqI/nOIJLYV+EEQ=")
    },
    "txnNumber" : NumberLong(127),
    "stmtId" : 0,
    "prevOpTime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
    },
    "o" : {
        ... contents of insert, around 20 small fields
    }
},
..... many more oplog entries
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1651706370, 30),
    "t" : NumberLong(39),
    "h" : NumberLong(0),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "n",
    "ns" : "somedatabase.somecollection",
    "ui" : UUID("3e459c38-cd32-48b7-a971-7fbe35e19a16"),
    "wall" : ISODate("2022-05-04T23:19:30.950Z"),
    "lsid" : {
        "id" : UUID("596e87e3-9774-453c-9436-b3f3bcfeb70e"),
        "uid" : BinData(0,"fBoXTP6tMwXzKDWLLyql/yjO5/7aXqI/nOIJLYV+EEQ=")
    },
    "txnNumber" : NumberLong(76),
    "stmtId" : 0,
    "prevOpTime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
    },
    "o" : {
        ... contents of insert, same as above
    }
}
```